# Material-ui - when click in a button, modal open multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this render():

```
render() {
const classes = this.useStyles();

return (
    <Paper style={classes.root}>
        <Table style={classes.table}>
            <TableBody>
                {this.state.deadTopics.map(row => (
                    <TableRow key={row.id}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                            {row.id}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">
                            <div>
                                <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={this.handleOpen}>
                                    Open alert dialog
                                </Button>
                                <Modal
                                    aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                                    aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
                                    open={this.state.setOpen}
                                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                                >
                                    <div style={classes.modal} style={classes.paper}>
                                        <p>ola</p>
                                    </div>
                                </Modal>
                            </div>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </Paper>
);
}
```

It looks good, render as expected.
**My problem is that:**
the element deadTopics is an array, and it generate the rows of table, when I click on the button to open the Modal, it open multiples modals, not the only one specific in the row.

How can I prevent this to happen?
I want that when I click in the button to open modal, it shows only the specific modal.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are opening all the Modals with the same state 'setOpen'. You need to have different state name for each row. Have a unique state name for every row like as follows -

```
open={this.state['some-unique-name']}

example - `setOpen-${row.id}`
```

and in onClick function -

```
onClick={() => this.handleOpen(row.id)}

handleOpen = (rowId) => {
     this.setState({
       [`setOpen-${rowId}`]: true
     })
```

Comment: But, with this approach, if I have thousand rows, I need to have thousand of unique values in the scope, is it okay? Doesn't look good to me

Comment: Yes that is fine because you cannot have a single state to control the behaviour of multiple Modal. They will behave independent of each other so need independent state to control them.

Comment: I have an alternative solution, could I extract the modal to other class and control open state from father component?

Comment: You could have a single state variable, but instead of a boolean it would be the rowid of the open modal. Then you could set the `open` attribute of the modal based on whether the state matches the rowid.